# Create a unique id column based on values in two different columns

Tags: r

I have table similar to:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(Cust_ID = c("1","2","2","3","1","3"), 
                        App_date = as.Date(c("2023-05-01","2023-05-02","2023-05-03","2023-05-06","2023-04-28","2023-04-04")),
                        Product = c("AA","AA","BB","AA","CC","BB"))
```

I want to create a column of unique id where for a same Cust_ID and App_date lying within a span of three days will have same unique id.

So I want the result data set to look like this:

```
result <- data.frame(Cust_ID = c("1","2","2","3","1","3"), 
                        App_date = as.Date(c("2023-05-01","2023-05-02","2023-05-03","2023-05-06","2023-04-28","2023-04-04")),
                        Product = c("AA","AA","BB","AA","CC","BB"),
                        Unique_id = c("A1","A2","A2","A3","A1","A4"))
```

How to do this in R?

Comment: Shouldn't the last unique ID be `A3`? Why is it `A4`?

Comment: I think there's a typo in your dataset. The last row in your `dataframe` has a date of `2023-05-04`, but it changed to `2023-04-04` in your `result`

Comment: Use a concatenate function such as `paste0`. For example, write `dataframe$Unique_id <- paste0('A', dataframe$Cust_ID)` and the new column will appear at the end of your data.